# Ошибка при создании пиксельного шейдера: "Exception thrown: read access violation. **PS** was nullptr"

Tags: c++, directx, шейдеры

Я изучаю DirectX с помощью ресурса [www.directxtutorial.com](http://www.directxtutorial.com). Я полностью выполнил все шаги для отображения треугольника на экране, но при попытке запуска готовой программы возникает эта ошибка. В тексте ошибки говорится, что переменная PS, в котором должно хранится бинарный код скомпилированного пиксельного шейдера, — пустой (nullptr).
[image: Снимок ошибки]

В моём случае, код пиксельного и вершинного шейдеров хранятся в одном файле. Может ли это быть причиной ошибки? Почему не указывается ошибка сначала на вершинный шейдер (так как он создаётся первым)?

Вот полный код программы и шейдеров (ошибка в методе InitPipeline):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

IDXGISwapChain* swapchain;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* backbuffer;
ID3D11Device* dev;
ID3D11DeviceContext* devcon;

ID3D11Buffer* pVBuffer;
ID3D11InputLayout* pLayout;
ID3D11VertexShader* pVS;
ID3D11PixelShader* pPS;

struct VERTEX
{
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    D3DXCOLOR Color;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);
void InitPipeline();
void InitGraphics();
void RenderFrame();
void CleanD3D();

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                            L"WindowClass1",
                            L"My Game",
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                            300,
                            300,
                            500,
                            400,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            hInstance,
                            NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    InitD3D(hWnd);
    RenderFrame();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    CleanD3D();
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
    scd.BufferCount = 1;
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;

    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
                                D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                &scd,
                                &swapchain,
                                &dev,
                                NULL,
                                &devcon);

    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, NULL);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = 800;
    viewport.Height = 600;
    devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    InitPipeline();
    InitGraphics();
}

void InitPipeline()
{
    ID3D10Blob* VS, * PS;
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "PShader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

    dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS);

    devcon->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };
    dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout);
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);
}

void InitGraphics()
{
    VERTEX OurVertices[] =
    {
        {0, 0.5f, 0, D3DXCOLOR{1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f}},
        {0.45f, -0.5f, 0, D3DXCOLOR{0, 1.0f, 0, 1.0f}},
        {-0.45f, -0.5f, 0, D3DXCOLOR{0, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f}}
    };
    // create a buffer in the video adapter
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX) * 3;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);
    // fill the buffer
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);
    memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));
    devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);
}

void RenderFrame()
{
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR{0, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f});

    UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    devcon->Draw(3, 0);
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}

void CleanD3D()
{
    swapchain->Release();
    dev->Release();
    devcon->Release();
    pVBuffer->Release();
    pVS->Release();
    pPS->Release();
}
```

```
struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    VOut output;

    output.position = position;
    output.color = color;

    return output;
}


float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
    return color;
}
```

Попробуйте, пожалуйста, запустить данную программу на вашей машине. У Вас тоже возникает данная ошибка?

ИЗМЕНЕНО: Я прочитал текст ошибки метода компиляции пиксельного шейдера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как теперь исправить программу?

Comment: Там еще для каждой функции надо проверять наличие ошибок. Ну а вообще вы видимо не в курсе, что такое [относительный путь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83).

Comment: Я попробовал переместить шейдеры в папку Resource Files.  Получается, нужно переместить его в папку с "My Game.cpp"?

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться, как работают относительные пути...

Comment: Я знаю как. Что именно нужно сделать?

Comment: Если бы вы знали, как они работают, то тогда такой вопрос бы не возник. Это реально одна из тех базовых тем, которые абсолютно обязательны для освоения всеми, кто собирается писать программы.

Comment: Я всё пробовал. Во все директории перемещал файл шейдеров — не помогло.

Comment: Тогда вам вопрос на засыпку - относительно какой папки вы указываете относительный путь? Ну а если не можете разобраться с относительными путями, то используйте абсолютные, или прописывайте шейдеры как строки в коде, чтобы упростить себе жизнь и не работать с файловой системой.

Comment: Попробовал и абсолютные пути. Может ли проблема быть в том, что в пути есть пробелы?

Comment: Нет. Пробелы в путях - это не проблема. Если путь абсолютный и указан верно, то значит проблема не в пути. Проверяйте наличие ошибок у функций.

Comment: *Проверяйте наличие ошибок у функций* - тут имелось ввиду открыть документацию к например D3DX11CompileFromFile, прочитать, как для нее следует проверять правильность срабатывания и добавить в свой код соотв. код обработки возникновения ошибок после вызова этой функции.

Comment: Я это и сделал только что. Проблема в самом шейдере. При его компиляции выдаёт ошибку. См. изменённый вопрос.

Comment: Там ошибка копипасты - для пиксельного шейдера передается строка `"vs_4_0"`, как для вершинного.

Comment: Всё так. Спасибо за подсказку.